# Share/Change global variable in different iframes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

My site has the condition below:

In Website1, I have a global variable named "Global.Name".

**When Website1, Subsite1-1 and Subsite1-2 are in the same domain, I can use top as the gate for those 3 sites**.
Similar code is as below.

```js
//in subsite1-1, we set the global variable

top.Global.Name = "Jack";

//in subsite1-2, we get the global variable as below

alert(top.Global.Name);
```

**However, the current condition is that, the domain of Website1 and subsite1-1&subsite1-2 are different now.**

My condition now:

Website1 domain: csm.Mysite.com

Subsite1-1 and Subsite 1-2 domain: csmnew.Mysite.com

**Now the cross domain policy stops me from using top as the gate.**

Is there any solution to get/set the global variable in this specific situation?
(I meant the parent and the child have different sub domain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written code below to replace 'top' object.

```js
var mySpace = {};

mySpace.common = {
  getDomainTop: function(windowObj) {
    var instance = this;
    try {
      windowObj.frameElement = windowObj.frameElement;
      if (windowObj.frameElement === null) {
        return windowObj;
      } else {
        instance.getDomainTop(windowObj.parent);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return windowObj;
    }
  }
};

Object.defineProperty(mySpace, "top", {
  get: function() {
    var instance = this;
    try {
      top.frameElement = top.frameElement;
      return top;
    } catch (e) {
      return instance.common.getDomainTop(window);
    }
  }
});
```

This part works well for my condition.
Another thing I need to do is replace 'top' with 'mySpace.top' as below

```js
//top.Global.Name = "Jack";
mySpace.top.Global.Name = "Jack";
```